# Issue installing therubyracer -v '0.12.1 succeeds before bundling on Windows

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, therubyracer, libv8

I am a Windows 8 user. I installed lib v8 with:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

Now I am facing trouble with installing `therubyracer`. Following is the error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --without-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried following other stackoverflow links but nothing seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Because **therubyracer-0.12.1** relys on **libv8-3.16.14.7**, you install **libv8-3.16.14.3** rather than **libv8-3.16.14.7** firstly, so there is a conflict.

It works for me:

```
$ gem uninstall libv8 
$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'
$ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```